# Can you explain the concept of "Yichus"?

Tags: family-members, genealogy

Where does the concept of yichus (meaning that the person descends from something akin to "good stock") come from? How is it judged?

Note: I am not asking about the halachic concept that a man must check the lineage of a potential wife, nor am I asking about the term used in kiddushin's "asara yuchsin" or even the idea that a man should strive to marry the daughter of a talmud chacham. I am asking about the term as it is commonly used today. For example "That boy is a catch! He has good "yichus".

Comment: "How is it judged?" seems to be like a question whose answers will take up enough room that you should leave "Where does [it] come from?" to another question (if you wish to ask it).

Answer (score 8):

Rabbi Yochanan said: Whoever is a talmid chacham, and his son is a talmid chacham, and his grandson is a talmid chacham, the Torah will never again stop from his descendants.

[Yoma 85a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=85&format=pdf)

We see, therefore, that yichus matters: If someone had three consecutive generations in his ancestors who were talmidei chachamim, the Torah will not stop from his descendants!

Comment: thank you, that is excellent but then I assume that you are defining yichus as synonymous with talmud chacham, correct?

Comment: @vram I was defining "yichus" as meaning ancestry. You asked `Where does the concept of yichus (meaning that the person descends from something akin to "good stock") come from? How is it judged?` My answer was to that question.

Comment: but you definition does not include any mention of being a good person/ keeping the torah. I just want to clarify.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't know if you are in the orthodox dating world but it seems the term yichus can mean many things including: he/she has money (or the parents do), he/she is a descendant of an illustrious family (meaning can trace lineage back to, for the sake of example, Rashi). Among many other things.

Comment: @vram You're right: As far as I know, being a good person and keeping the Torah is not part of yichus (though it is of course more important than yichus).

Comment: @vram, "yichus" meaning that they or their parents are wealthy? I'm pretty sure I've never heard it used like that. If it is, then the term is certainly being abused.

Comment: @HodofHod that is exactly why I'm asking.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - What does *Gezhe* mean?

Answer (score 4):

I found the commonly stated view expressed [here](http://matzav.com/rav-brazil-on-parshas-naso-2) (Some terms translated).

> Yichus can be compared to 20 zeros. It is worthless unless each person
>   puts a one in front of them. A Jew must endeavour to align himself
>   with his forebears and only by doing so can he activate and draw from
>   all their strengths which they invested in the future generations.